# MySQL query result - memcahed using java

Tags: java, mysql, memcached

I am really new to Memcache. I just tested Memcache in Java and it works fine. I want to store MySQL query result in Memcache key. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient;
public class memfunc implements java.io.Serializable{
    Connection conn;
    private int urlid;
    private String er;
    private static MemcachedClient c = null;
static {
      try {
c = new MemcachedClient(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1",11211));
} catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.exit(-1);
      }
   }
public float[][] avgInfo(){
        String key=host;
        host=hostParser(host);
        String[] info=new String[6];
        if(c.get(key)==null && key==host){
                 ---------your code----
Future<Boolean> set= c.set(key, 3600, info);
             }
    return (String[]) c.get(key);}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I had the inclination to do it that way, I'd write a quick serializer/deserializer using ByteArray[Output/Input]Stream and Object[Output/Input]Stream, and store the resulting byte array using memcache. You may need to read the results into an array and then serialize to do this, but experiment to see what works.

IMO you're probably better off using some form of JPA, which will handle the caching issue for you, without the messiness of caches that can go stale.  Look into Hibernate/Eclipselink if you can, as that will likely give you better performance (less serialization) and avoid stale cache issues.

JBoss Cache can also handle pojos, so if your data is represented by java objects (JPA always is) you can store results in JBoss Cache. POJOs can just as easily serialize, and be stored in memcached as well.

The options I presented above are:

- Serialize the MySQL Results/Result array and store in memcached
- Use JPA and its internal cache. (Implementation dependent)
- Use a cache framework like JBoss Cache to store the MySQL Results/Result array OR JPA results
- Serialize the JPA/POJO results to memcached

Answer (score 0):

If your using Spymemcached then you just need to put the result of the query into a Serializable object and send it to memcached. For example,

client.set("keyname", 0, object);

where the type of object is a serializable object that holds the query result. Spymemcached will take care of doing all of the serialization and when you get the object later Spymemcached will deserialize the object for you.